# Java Generic Class with the Generic-Type extending multiple other classes

Tags: java, class, generics, extend

I can't wrap my head around it at the moment, maybe that's a stupid question but I give it a go.

Lets say I have these Classes:

```
class CellType1 {

    public void doSomething(){
      // does something ClassType1 specific
    }
}

class CellType2 {

    public void doSomething(){
       // does something ClassType2 specific
    }
}

class CellType3 {

    public void doSomething(){
       // does something ClassType3 specific
    }
}
```

These classes share the same functions but the functions themselves work differently. Now I have this Class:

```
 class Map<CellTypes>{
   CellTypes cell;

    //...
        public void function(){
           cell.doSomething();
        }

    //...

    }
```

This Class' Generic Type will later be one of the three upper classes. And in this class I want to access the doSomething()-Function for this specific CellType-Object. I've tried doing

```
class Map<CellTypes extends CellType1, CellType2, CellType3> {
/*...*/
}
```

But this limits me to the function/s of CellType1. 
How can I use the functions from different Classes in a Generic class?
Maybe someone has a better idea than me!
I hope this was understandable.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

I need to have my Class Map as a Generic Class, because I need to create different objects of map and pass them the CellType-class they need to be working with.

Comment: You can't. Why don't they have a common supertype?

Comment: Can't you make the three `CellType*` classes extend a common interface or class?

Comment: Have all three classes extend or implement a super class/interface, then have your map's generic be that supertype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an interface:

```
interface CellType {
    public void doSomething();
}
```

And implement the interface like this:

```
class CellType1 implements CellType {

    public void doSomething(){
      // does something ClassType1 specific
    }
}

class CellType2 implements CellType {

    public void doSomething(){
       // does something ClassType2 specific
    }
}

class CellType3 implements CellType {

    public void doSomething(){
       // does something ClassType3 specific
    }
}
```

`Map` class:

```
class Map<T extends CellType> {
   T cell;

    //...
        public void function(){
           cell.doSomething();
        }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this is what I was looking for! But sadly you can only use the "extends" keyword in the generic brackets - does it still work if I'm extending an intrface?

Comment: @kalu you cannot `extends` a `interface`, its a syntax error. only can `extends` a class. read about interface first: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Comment: I tried this and it works perfectly. Not to forget for future readers: When you instantiate an Object e.g. of Map<CellType1> obj = new Map<>; You need to assign obj.cell = new CellType1(); for it to work aswell.

Comment: @Blasanka An interface can extend another interface.

Comment: Yes it is. And I talked about classes

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface CanDoSomething {
    public void doSomething();
}
```

Then all the other classes implement this interface.  This works only if the method signature is the same in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface CellType {
   void doSomething();   
}
class CellType1 implements CellType {
    public void doSomething(){
        //your logic
    }
}
//similar implementation logic for CellType2 and CellType3
class Map {
   private CellType cellType;
   public Map(CellType cellType){
       this.cellType = cellType;
   }
   public void someFunc(){
      cellType.doSomething();
   } 
}
```

Hope this helps